# INSERT INTO variable in python

Tags: python, variables, insert

Code:

```
def execute():
    cursor.execute('''
                    INSERT INTO Testb(First_name, Last_name, Tel_number, Address)
                    VALUES(?,?,?,?)
                  ''')
    conn.commit()
```

Can we add a different type of value to the `VALUES`? My intent is to insert an output to the value which is outside the function. As an example, if I get the output `x=456` in which `x` is the variable, how can I insert it to the `Tele_number` to the corresponding value?

Comment: `Can we add a different type of value` — different to what?

Comment: `def execute(some_param): ...` allows you to pass parameters (i.e. variables) into the function.  Combine that with [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and you get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use str.format() to allow multiple substitutions and value formatting.

For your case:

```
def execute():
    first_name = 'Twilight'
    last_name = 'Moon'
    telephone = '4569876521'
    address = 'Somewhere, '
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Testb(First_name, Last_name, Tel_number, Address)
                    VALUES({},{},{},{})".format(first_name, last_name, telephone, address))
    conn.commit()
```

Refer to [this link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/format) to learn more about string formatting in python.